# Multiple search & replace - Notepad ++ (regex)

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have a list of words, for example:

```
 Good -> Bad
 Sky -> Blue
 Gray -> Black
```

etc...

What is the best why to do find&replace in notepad++? 
I tried this:

```
FIND: (Good)|(Sky)|(Gray)

Replace: (?1Bad)(?2Blue)(?3Black)
```

but it doesn't work :(
any idea? or suggestions ?

Comment: Do them one at a time.

Comment: A replacement string can only contain place-holders for capture groups but no conditional statements.

Comment: You can't do this is one action. And as single actions, you don't need regex.

Comment: I have a list of 17K rows, what is the best way?!

Answer (score 0):

There is however a workaround if you add this newline at the end of your text *(it must be the last line, so don't press enter at the end)*:

```
#Good:Bad#Sky:Blue#Gray:Black#
```

and if you use this pattern:

```
(Good|Blue|Black)(?=(?:.*\R)++#(?>[^#]+#)*?\1:([^#]+))|\R.++(?!\R)
```

with this replacement:

```
$2
```

pattern details:

```
(Good|Blue|Black)  # this part capture the word in group 1
(?=                # then we reach the last line in a lookakead
    (?:.*\R)++     # match all the lines until the last line
    #(?>[^#]+#)*?  # advance until the good value is found 
    \1             # the good value (backreference to the capture group 1)
    : ([^#]+)      # capture the replacement in group 2
)                  # close the lookbehind

|                  # OR

\R.++(?!\R)        # match the last line (to remove it)
```

Note: to make the pattern more efficient, you can put it in a non capturing group and add a lookahead at the begining with all the first possible characters to quickly discard useless positions in the string:

```
(?=[GB\r\n])(?:\b(Good|Blue|Black)\b(?=(?:.*\R)++#(?>[^#]+#)*?\1:([^#]+))|\R.++(?!\R))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have a list of 17K.
The list includes oldkeyword = new keyword

what is the best way?

Comment: @AdamLem: In this case why do you use notepad++? It's clearly not the way to go, use a programming language.